# Google Cloud Build with kaniko cache fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, kaniko

I'm using Google Cloud Build along with kaniko cache for speedup. Until recently if worked perfectly, but now it's failing with

```
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 137
```

I assume, it's because builder is running out of memory

Is there a way to select higher level VM for this or increase memory?

I'm using the same standard configuration that is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/kaniko-cache#:%7E:text=cache%20expiration%20time-,Overview,the%20open%20source%20tool%20Kaniko).

Thanks in advance

P.s. Regular builds with `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker` are going through

Comment: With this `Is there a way to select higher level VM for this or increase memory` you mean the VM that is building your app, not the actual instance where it will be hosted, right?

Comment: Right, because actual instances are performing well. The problem is during build process itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, all you have to do is specify what machine type you want to use during your build at the build command, as you can see in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/speeding-up-builds#using_custom_virtual_machine_sizes) where there are also examples with how to start builds with this special machines is gcloud, Yaml and JSON .

Currently the machine types available for this are

```
UNSPECIFIED     Standard machine type.
N1_HIGHCPU_8    Highcpu machine with 8 CPUs.
N1_HIGHCPU_32   Highcpu machine with 32 CPUs.
E2_HIGHCPU_8    Highcpu e2 machine with 8 CPUs.
E2_HIGHCPU_32   Highcpu e2 machine with 32 CPUs.
```

And you can find more information on those specific types of machines in [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for, missed this bit in docs. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue. I forgot to run this command to [activate kaniko cache](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/kaniko-cache?hl=ja#enabling_kaniko_cache_in_your_builds).

`gcloud config set builds/use_kaniko True`

After that, the error disappeared.